# Flask easy_install error windows 7

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, flask

When I follow the instructions on http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/ I get the following error when I execute 'easy_install' in the windows command line interpreter:

```
error: No urls, filenames, or requirements specified (see --help)
```

Why do I get this error?

Btw, I ran ez_setup.py and it works because there are easy_install files in my 'Scripts' folder of my python folder.

Comment: could you include the exact command you enter ?

Comment: I did what Thomas said and it worked. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what's supposed to happen when you run the command `easy_install`.  The Flask installation instructions you link to tell you to type

```
> easy_install virtualenv
```

not

```
> easy_install
```